# Spark build.sbt file versioning

Tags: scala, apache-spark, version

I am having a hard time understanding the multiple version numbers going into the build.sbt file for spark programs.

```
1. version
2. scalaVersion
3. spark version?
4. revision number.
```

There are multiple compatibility between these versions as well. 
Can you please explain how to decide these versions for my project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope the following SBT lines and their comments will be sufficient to explain your question.

```
// The version of your project itself.
// You can change this value whenever you want,
// e.g. everytime you make a production release.
version := "0.1.0"

// The Scala version your project uses for compile.
// If you use spark, you can only use a 2.11.x version.
// Also, because Spark includes its own Scala in runtime
// I recommend you use the same one;
//you can check which one your Spark instance uses in the spark-shell.
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

// The spark version the project uses for compile.
// Because you wont generate an uber jar with Spark included,
// but deploy your jar to an spark cluster instance.
// This version must match with the remote one, unless you want weird bugs...
val SparkVersion = "2.3.1"
// Note, I use a val with the Spark version
// to make it easier to include several Spark modules in my project,
// this way, if I want/have to change the Spark version,
// I only have to modify one line,
// and avoid strange erros because I changed some versions, but not others.
// Also note the 'Provided' modifier at the end,
// it indicates SBT that it shouldn't include the Spark bits in the generated jar
// neither in package nor assembly tasks.
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % SparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % SparkVersion % Provided,
)

// Exclude Scala from the assembly jar, because spark already includes it.
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
```

You should also take care of the SBT version, that is the version of the SBT used in your project. You set it in the *"project/build.properties"* file.

```
sbt.version=1.2.3
```

**Note:**
I use the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin, to generate a jar with all dependencies included except Spark and Scala. This is usefull if you use other libraries like the MongoSparkConnector for example.