Scala doesn't detect MANIFEST.MD leading: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
I am very aware that this covers the same error and output Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.
The distinction here is i'm not using Java, I'm using Scala.  I have not seen a question that solves the .ClassNotFoundException for Scala.  I've tried:

specify MANIFEST.MF

john@oak:~/IdeaProjects/sss/src/main/scala$ jar -cvfm myJar.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF core/LoadSymbol.scala
added manifest
adding: core/LoadSymbol.scala(in = 221) (out= 158)(deflated 28%) # success
john@oak:~/IdeaProjects/sss/src/main/scala$ java -jar myJar.jar # failure 
Error: Could not find or load main class core.LoadSymbol
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: core.LoadSymbol


specfiy classpath and MANIFEST.MF

john@oak:~/IdeaProjects/sss/src/main/scala$ java -jar -classpath . myJar.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF core/LoadSymbol.scala # looks correct, bad syntax 
Error: Could not find or load main class myJar.jar 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myJar.jar


Using jar [options] (notice the first command succeeds without specifying MANIFEST.MF)

john@oak:~/IdeaProjects/sss/src/main/scala$ jar cfe myJar.jar LoadSymbol core/LoadSymbol.scala
john@oak:~/IdeaProjects/sss/src/main/scala$ java -jar myJar.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class LoadSymbol
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LoadSymbol

john@oak:~/IdeaProjects/sss/src/main/scala$ jar -cvfm myJar.jar core/LoadSymbol.scala
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:409)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:232)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:82)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:74)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:268)
        at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1686)
john@oak:~/IdeaProjects/sss/src/main/scala$ 

File system tree layout
total 40
drwxrwxr-x 6 john john 4096 Aug 18 20:40 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 john john 4096 Aug 15 22:02 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john  176 Aug 11 21:40 Constants.scala
drwxrwxr-x 2 john john 4096 Aug 16 11:45 core
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john   47 Aug 16 22:20 manifest.txt
drwxrwxr-x 2 john john 4096 Aug 16 22:29 META-INF
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john  659 Aug 18 20:40 myJar.jar
drwxrwxr-x 2 john john 4096 Aug 16 11:17 schemas
drwxrwxr-x 2 john john 4096 Jul 31 18:20 technical

contents of META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: core/LoadSymbol

uses the file: core/LoadSymbol.scala, contents of core/LoadSymbol.scala:
package core
import core.EndpointDataLoader.{fromAPI, toDatabase}

object LoadSymbol extends App {

  private val table = System.getenv("FOO")

  val symbolDataFrame = fromAPI()
  toDatabase(symbolDataFrame, table)
}

I've tried setting source files/ folders
I've found that Java versions can cause issues: - Answered on Sep 20, 2020 (not recent enough) that says to use Java 8, and there were on the higher version 14.  Java I'm using 11.0.23

What is the meta problem you are trying to solve? Produce an executable JAR? Just use a plugin that does everything for you like sbt-assembly - Also, App can cause problems with Spark, just write a regular main method. - Also, usually you don't write executable Spark programs because you usually want a full Spark cluster.

There's no specific Scala ClassNotFoundException, it's the same as with Java and same reasons for it to appear apply. That being said, it sounds like your main issue is in the way you're creating the JAR. As said by Luis: any reason to not use a standard build tool which will handle this for you?

Additionally: JVM - no matter if it works on bytecode generated by Scala, Java, Clojure, Goovy, Kotlin or whatever - reads .class files. Your jar -cvfm myJar.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF core/LoadSymbol.scala puts source code into the jar (which JVM can interpret at best as a resource, not executable code).

I am trying to produce an executable JAR.  @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I'm interested in your spark statement.  The complete problem I'm trying to solve is using a JAR to be executed by Airflow's spark-submit operator.  The JAR is running using env vars passed down by airflow -- effectively parameterizing a process.  I do not know of any build systems -> naive.

@MichaelSchmidt this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371961/spark-build-sbt-file-versioning/52375099#52375099 - The versions in the answer as well as some statements are outdated but it may help you create a proper uber JAR to submit to airflow, just note it won't be executable. Anyways, be sure to update everything according to the versions of your cluster.
